# Problem fetching workflow intance from DB

Tags: elsa-workflows

I'm using elsa-workflow v1.5 and trying to resume a workflow when user commit an action, by fetching the related workflow instance from db using this method

```
await _workflowInstanceStore.ListAllAsync()
```

But got an error about the data reader being open

Now I'm wondering if it is a valid approach? and if it is, how can I resolve this error?

Comment: I can't solve it straight-up but I can tell you that "reader already open" is often a symptom of having a combination of asynchronous operations and lazy-loading from an ORM. Are you using Entity Framework by any chance?

Comment: I'm using Elsa.Persistence.EntityFramework.SqlServer and trying to fetch a WFinstance using the code I provided in the question. My guess is that you're correct but I can't find how does it happen, I'm just testing a simple scenario

Comment: Could you post a more complete stack trace for the exception you have?  Feel free to redact or alter any names of stuff in your own app.  Although frames which relate to reading/writing data or reading/writing properties of an Elsa object then that's quite important.

The more complete description of what happens is that Entity Framework is trying to lazy-load (IE: Trigger a DB query) for a property of an object, whilst it already has an query (perhaps async) in progress.  I'm interested to see if there's a property getter near the top of the stack.

Comment: This is the second time I've seen someone running into this issue. I'm pretty sure this is an issue with the EF Core persistence provider for Elsa 1.x. Elsa 2 makes sure this doesn't happen by using short-lived DB contexts. If you open an issue on GitHub with repro steps, we can look into fixing this in Elsa 1.x .Perhaps even using the same strategy used in Elsa 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the code you are using is valid. What you are experiencing is caused by the way Elsa 1.5 manages the DB context.

Unless you are willing to fork Elsa 1.5 and reimplement the persistence EF Core provider or provide your own implementation of the persistence abstractions, I'm afraid there's no simple way to resolve this error other than upgrading to Elsa 2.0 where this is fixed.